# Error with SELECT statement in a FOR loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When I try to execute the code below I receive this error here:

> Error(9,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting
>   one of the following:     ( ) - + case mod new not null          table continue avg count current exists max min prior sql
>   stddev sum variance execute multiset the both leading    trailing
>   forall merge year month day hour minute second    timezone_hour
>   timezone_minute timezone_region timezone_abbr    time timestamp
>   interval date

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_LIST_SIMILAR_TVSERIES
(seriesName IN SERIES.NAME%TYPE)
AS
  CURSOR series IS (SELECT IDS FROM SERIES WHERE NAME = seriesName);
  allSeries SERIES%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
FOR series IN allSeries
  (SELECT 2* ( SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM   DICT d
               WHERE  d.idt IN ( SELECT DISTINCT IDT
                                 FROM   POSTING
                                 WHERE  IDS = series
                               INTERSECT
                                 SELECT DISTINCT IDT
                                 FROM   POSTING
                                 WHERE IDS = allSeries.IDS
                               )
             )
         / ( ( SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(IDT)
               FROM   POSTING
               WHERE  IDS = series
             ) +
             ( SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(IDT)
               FROM   POSTING
               WHERE  IDS = allSeries.IDS )
           )
  INTO   similarity
  FROM   SERIES s1
         SERIES s2
  WHERE  s1.IDS = series
  AND    s2.IDS != series
  );

  IF similarity > 0.7 THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ok');
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

What the code does is take in a name, find it's ID, and compare it to other id's (and avoid comparing it to the same ID). I'm trying to print out "ok" whenever the similarity calculation is over 0.7 . No idea why this doesn't work.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1155

Comment: What if I don't have a column for the calculation but I need it to be individual for every compared ID?

Comment: In your example you are not executing the cursor to fetch the IDS from for that seriesName to populate the allSeries variable, so your cursor loop is fetching nothing. And please, please,PLEASE stop using the same name for the cursor and table - it is confusing!

Comment: `FOR ... IN (SELECT ... ) LOOP` you are missing the `LOOP` keyword (and I have no idea what you are trying to achieve with the `allSeries` variable as your use of it appears to be syntactically invalid). You are also missing and `END IF;` statement at the end.

Comment: Good point, I just realised that allSeries doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

> I am still trying to understand the logic in the SQL statement. But i
>   have hopefully tried to remove the syntactical error. Hope it helps.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_LIST_SIMILAR_TVSERIES(
    seriesName IN SERIES.NAME%TYPE)
AS
similarity PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN
  (SELECT IDS FROM SERIES WHERE NAME = seriesName
  )
  LOOP
    --The logic i am still not able to understand
    SELECT          *,
      (SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM DICT d
      WHERE d.idt IN
        ( SELECT DISTINCT IDT FROM POSTING WHERE IDS = I.IDS
        INTERSECT
        SELECT DISTINCT IDT
        FROM POSTING
        WHERE IDS = allSeries.IDS
        ) / (
        (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(IDT) FROM POSTING WHERE IDS = i.IDS
        ) +
        (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(IDT) FROM POSTING WHERE IDS = I.IDS
        ) )
      )
    INTO similarity
    FROM SERIES s1,
      SERIES s2
    WHERE s1.IDS  = s2.IDS
    AND s2.IDS   != I.IDS;
    IF similarity > 0.7 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ok');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: YEah, hard to parse that query! You'll need a "similarity" variable, though, to select into with your implementation.

Comment: I realise now that allSeries doesn't make sense. I was attempting to use it as an "array" of the SERIES table but it's stupid and I don't know how it would've worked. I've tried your code but it doesn't work because of the allSeries variable. I'll try to edit it so it would actually make sense.

Comment: made the changes @Micheal :)

Comment: Yeah Lemoncide plz try ti and if suppose it helped plz marked it as accepted so it would be helpful to others too.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have a cursor named the same as the table, what is the series%rowtype going to look like? The cursor or the table? Bad idea.

Second, you never execute the cursor to get the ID, so your subsequent cursor loop is looking for records that match allSeries.IDS which is null because you haven't populated it.

Try this as a starting point, although I'm guessing that you still will have work to do on your cursor query. Still, at least it points you to the right code structures...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_LIST_SIMILAR_TVSERIES
   (seriesName IN SERIES.NAME%TYPE)
AS 
   CURSOR seriesCur IS (SELECT IDS FROM SERIES WHERE NAME = seriesName);

   allSeries seriesCur%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
  OPEN seriesCur;
  FETCH seriesCur INTO allSeries;
  IF seriesCur%NOTFOUND
  THEN
    CLOSE seriesCur;
    raise_application_error(-20001,'Your SeriesName does not exist');
  END IF;
  CLOSE seriesCur;

 FOR seriesRec IN 
   -- this query is a mess! Tried to fix up some aspects of it according to what I THINK you're trying to do. 
  (SELECT 2*
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DICT d WHERE d.idt IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT IDT FROM POSTING WHERE IDS = allSeries.IDS
  INTERSECT
  SELECT DISTINCT IDT FROM POSTING WHERE IDS = allSeries.IDS))
  / ((SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(IDT) FROM POSTING WHERE IDS = allSeries.IDS) +
  (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(IDT) FROM POSTING WHERE IDS = allSeries.IDS) ) similarity
  FROM SERIES s1, SERIES s2
  WHERE s1.IDS = allSeries.IDS
  AND s2.IDS != allSeries.IDS)
LOOP

    IF seriesRec.similarity > 0.7 THEN 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ok'); 
    END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```